# correlated rows for paired columns

Tags: r

I am looking for a method to correlate adjacant rows in a data.frame using pearson correlation or similar. I want to correlate row1-row2, row3-row4 etc. The correlation should be paired based on the columns. Is there a way to do this in R

```
> head(BindTissueSerumSort)
                                  020         045         080         082        084        086         088        090
hsa-miR-99b-5p.dataTissue  0.96980500  1.32387470 -1.32165937 -0.64061449  0.7512897 -0.1502014 -0.47235641 -0.2801984
hsa-miR-99b-5p.dataSerum  -1.01659519  0.63873118  1.20920323 -0.02219251 -0.1986268  0.5351617  0.38003350 -0.1744776
hsa-miR-99a-5p.dataTissue -0.09451709 -2.70764352  0.20155679  0.56183644 -1.0409176 -0.1489536  0.21819883  0.3711749
hsa-miR-99a-5p.dataSerum  -0.97297544 -0.10758543 -0.02442682 -0.21588054  1.8790067 -0.7815082  2.12159150 -0.3951215
hsa-miR-98-5p.dataTissue   0.69694927 -0.07233065 -0.88524941 -0.83712359  1.7260447 -0.7358599  0.06612543  0.4686154
hsa-miR-98-5p.dataSerum   -1.17634730  0.59454306  1.07522464 -0.95907146 -1.2341767  0.7373701 -1.05066066 -0.7045416
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df <- t(BindTissueSerumSort)
idx <- seq(1, ncol(df), 2)
sapply(idx, function(x) cor(df[, x], df[, x+1]) )
```